# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_glClear", referenced from: _main in main.cpp.o arm64 GLFW3

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

So i was build a `GLFW` program with cmake
Everthing went fine
Until i build it and `make` give me this error
`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_glClear", referenced from: _main in main.cpp.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`
I try with this command `CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` And this `link_directories` Still not working i have no idea what's going on here.

Edit:
Here are my CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)

project(TESTING)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "~/DEV/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx")
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "~/DEV/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
link_directories(~/DEV/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/lib)

find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE glfw)
```

Comment: Do you use `target_link_libraries` to link with the actual GL library? How do you do that? Please show us your `CMakeLists.txt` file ([edit] your question to copy-paste it as text).

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You link with only the `glfw` library, not any other OpenGL libraries.

Comment: Thanks for responding I am using ``GLFW`` With ``GLAD`` Right now, But how will I use GLAD for GLFW?

Comment: I mean you need to link with the `GL` library as well: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE glfw GL)`

Comment: Well, that error is fixed but I still have some errors here ``[ 50%] Linking CXX executable TESTING
ld: library not found for -lGL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER: So you need to add this line: `"-framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo"` in the `CMAKELISTS` on `target_link_libraries` Or you can use `"-framework OpenGL"` but if you use all the solution up there it will give you some warning.
I don't know but if you don't see any warning I think I'm using `vcpkg` **incorrectly**
And this Question is **SOLVED**